# Notational confusion. Conformal Mapping and First Fundamental Form

Tags: differential-geometry

[image]
In the chain rule shouldn’t it be $\sigma_{\tilde u}$ for the second one? How do they get just $\sigma_u$ for both?[image]

Comment: What do you mean? I see $\sigma_{u}$s and $\sigma_{v}$s.

Comment: See the definition of the two curves, I’m talking about second curve.

Comment: The second curve is defined in terms of $\tilde u$ and $\tilde v$ isn’t it?

Comment: Yes. But the symbol $\sigma_{u}$ should be understood simply as the differential of $\sigma$ with respect to its first argument, and $\sigma_{v}$ as the differential with respect to its second argument. The notation is perhaps misleading in that specific values of $u$ and $v$ are not involved in the definition of $\sigma_{u}$ and $\sigma_{v}$.

Comment: I’m not getting you. Are they not completely different curves and $u$ is totally different from $\tilde u$? How can the first argument can be $u$ for both the cases? I tried referring many other books and not getting a clear answer.

Comment: How the values of $u$ and $v$ are not involved? And if as you say it is just the differential with respect to first and second argument, in the book he uses the dot product of $\sigma_u$ with itself to get $E$ in the first fundamental form. But here as per the notation I’m getting $\sigma_u.\sigma_{\tilde u}$ which is not at all $E$.

Comment: Suppose if my curves are $\sigma(cost,sint)$ and $\sigma(e^t,sint)$ can we say $\sigma_u$ is same for both?

Comment: Let's just take a step back and ignore the notation... you understand that the angle between the curves is calculated from the "derived cosine" of the tangents to the curves at a point p, yes?

Comment: What do you mean by derived cosine?

Comment: Yes angle is calculated from tangents at a point. How do you relate that here?

Comment: Can you explain please?

Comment: There are too many dots and tildes and dots on tildes in this notation! And they don't display correctly on my machine :(
Suppose $\gamma(t)=\sigma(\cos t, \sin t)$ and $\tilde{\gamma}(t)=\sigma(\exp t,
\sin t)$. Then $\dot{\gamma}(t)=-\sigma_{u}\sin t+\sigma_{v}\cos t$ and $\dot{\tilde{\gamma}}(t)=\sigma_{u}\exp t + \sigma_{v}\cos t$. So $\dot{\gamma}\cdot\dot{\tilde{\gamma}}= -(\sigma_{u}\cdot\sigma_{u})\exp t\sin t + (\sigma_{u}\cdot\sigma_{v})(-\sin t \cos t + \exp t \cos t) + (\sigma_{v}\cdot\sigma_{v})\cos^{2} t$.

Comment: Yes all those $\sigma_{u}$s refer to the same vector-valued function defined on the plane, the rate of change of $\sigma$ with respect to its first argument. So where $\sigma_{u}\cdot\sigma_{u}$ appears one might instead write $\lvert \sigma_{u}\rvert^{2}$. That is the E you are worried about? Why so?

Comment: I’ve added a new picture. While doing chain rule why it is $\sigma_u$ both the times rather than $\sigma_u$ and $\sigma_{\tilde u}$? If it is same we can write $E$. This notation is driving me crazy.

Comment: Probably when $\sigma$ was first introduced its first argument was labelled just $u$ and its second $v$. So the notation $\sigma_{u}$ seemed very natural for its partial derivative with respect to its first argument, and $\sigma_{v}$ for its partial derivative with respect to its second. An alternative which might have made you happier would be $\partial_{1}\sigma$ for the first and $\partial_{2}\sigma$ for the second.

Comment: Sorry btw, in my computations earlier for $\dot{\gamma}\cdot\dot{\tilde{\gamma}}$ in the specific case, I failed to recognise distinct $t_{0}$ and $\tilde{t}_{0}$